# Retry Runnable java

Tags: java, multithreading, error-handling

I want to make class to retry doing what I want if specific exception happen for n times before throwing exception, so I write below class and used Builder to build it could you please review it and update me with your feedback:

```
public class Retry implements Runnable {
private final long sleep;
private final Runnable r;
private final int times;
private final Predicate<Throwable> p;
private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

private Retry(Builder b) {
    this.r = b.r;
    this.times = b.times;
    this.p = b.p;
    this.sleep = b.sleep;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        r.run();
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        if (counter.getAndIncrement() < times && p.test(th))
            handle(th);
        else
            throw th;
    }
}

private void handle(Throwable th) {
    System.out.println("handel #"+counter.get());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sleep);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    run();
}

public static class Builder {
    private final static long SLEEP = 1000;
    private final static int TIMES = 5;
    private final Runnable r;
    private int times;
    private long sleep;
    private Predicate<Throwable> p;

    public Builder(Runnable r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public static Builder of(Runnable r) {
        return new Builder(r);
    }

    public Builder times(int times) {
        this.times = times;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder sleep(long sleep) {
        this.sleep = sleep;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder on(Predicate<Throwable> p) {
        this.p = p;
        return this;
    }

    public Retry build() {
        if (this.sleep <= 0)
            this.sleep = SLEEP;
        if (this.times <= 0)
            this.times = TIMES;
        if (this.p == null)
            this.p = th -> true;
        return new Retry(this);
    }
}
}
```

how to use it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Runnable r = () -> {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Test");
};
runAsync(
        Retry.Builder.of(r).times(10)
                .on(th -> th instanceof IllegalStateException).build())
        .join();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Defaulting to properties inside the `Builder`

You should perform validation inside the `times(int)`, `sleep(int)` and `on(Predicate)` to either warn callers of invalid values, if not to throw an `Exception`. Even if you don't and prefer to silently use the default values, this is what you can do:

```
public Builder times(int times) {
    this.times = times <= 0 ? TIMES : times;
    return this;
}

public Builder sleep(long sleep) {
    this.sleep = sleep <= 0 ? SLEEP : sleep;
    return this;
}

public Builder on(Predicate<Throwable> p) {
    this.p = Optional.ofNullable(p).orElse(th -> true);
    return this;
}

public Retry build() {
    return new Retry(this);
}
```

## Retry logic

This is roughly how it looks like currently:

```
Retry.run();
    r.run();
        |_ (Exception) handle(th);
                            |_ (after sleeping) r.run();
```

The problem here is that you will simply have a cascading chain of calling `r.run()` on the method call stack, which may result in `StackOverflowError` if it gets too deep.

You should consider doing the retrying within `run()` itself as such:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // edit: should be < times so that it doesn't run for the (times + 1)-th time
    // while (counter.getAndIncrement() <= times) {
    while (counter.getAndIncrement() < times) {
        try {
            r.run();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            if (counter.get() <= times && p.test(th)) {
                handle(th);
            } else {
                throw th;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void handle(Throwable th) {
    // corrected typo below
    System.out.println("handle #" + counter.get());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sleep);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    // don't need to call again
    // run();
}
```

## Design

Not much to comment here, but here is one open-ended question to ponder about:

1. Is it always safe to call `r.run()` again for your use cases?

In other words, are there things to clean up/reinitialize across restarts?

Comment: good feedback I'll take it in my consideration, but there is 2 points: 1- there is no need to check '(counter.get() <= times)' again while is enough, 2- the handle method was just log and sleep I can move it inside run.

Comment: for clean up/reinit thinking for make beforeRunnable to be executed before each r.run(), will update my code and upload it.

Comment: @BassemRedaZohdy the second check is to make sure `th` is properly thrown after the last attempt. :)

Comment: @BassemRedaZohdy btw see edited code, think I got the `while()` condition wrong initially.